# How do I script an install?

Tags: server, installation

Does anybody know of some documentation that would show me the best way to create a scripted install of Ubuntu Server (10.04)?

Answer (score 4):

You want to do a kickstart or debian-installer preseed:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/installation-guide/i386/automatic-install.html